# Getting crazy large numbers, possibly due to improper manipulation of doubles and ints (C language)

Tags: c, function, int, double

I'm writing a program for my CS239 class in C that asks for cost of something, amount paid, calculates tax, and then determines what type of change to return and optimal coins to return.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void coinage(int c, int q, int d, int n, int p); //change calculation function

int main(void)
{
   double price, tax, paid, due, t_back; //used double instead of int for decimal purpose
   int c, b, q, d, n, p; //change, bills, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies

   printf("\nProgram Author: PuppyBreath\n");
   printf("\nEnter price in dollars: $");
   scanf("%lf", &price);

      tax = 1.06;
      due = price*tax;

   printf("Sales tax in Kentucky is 6%, therefore the amount due is $%.2f. \n", due);
   printf("Enter amount paid: \n");
   scanf("%lf", &paid);

      paid = paid*100+0.5;
      due = due*100;
      c = paid-due;
      b = c/100;
      t_back = (paid-due)/100-0.01; //used a double rather than an int for increased precision

   coinage(c, q, d, n, p); //calls coinage function

   printf("Change back:\n");
   printf("Total: $%.2f\n", t_back);

   if(t_back >= 1)
      printf("Ones: %d\n", b);
   else
      printf("No bills\n");

   if(q >= 1)
      printf("Quarters: %d\n", q);
   else
      printf("NO QUARTERS FOR YOU!\n");

   if(d >= 1)
      printf("Dimes: %d\n", d);
   else
      printf("NO DIMES FOR YOU!\n");

   if(n >= 1)
      printf("Nickels: %d\n", n);
   else
      printf("NO NICKELS FOR YOU!\n");

   if(p >= 1)
      printf("Pennies: %d\n", p);
   else
      printf("NO PENNIES FOR YOU!\n");

   return 0;
}

void coinage(int change, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies)
{
   int t_change, t_quarters, t_dimes, t_nickels, t_pennies;

   t_change = change%100;  //use mod to carry remainders and dividing to find number of each   coin
   t_quarters = t_change/25.00;
   t_change = t_change%25;
   t_dimes = t_change/10.00;
   t_change = t_change%10;
   t_nickels = t_change/5.00;
   t_change = t_change%5;
   t_pennies = t_change+0.5;

   quarters = t_quarters;
   dimes = t_dimes;
   nickels = t_nickels;
   pennies = t_pennies;
}
```

This is my code, and after I compile it this is what happens: *(the '8' and '10' are my inputs)*

./a.out

```
Program Author: PuppyBreath

Enter price in dollars: $8 
Sales tax in Kentucky is 6%, therefore the amount due is $8.48.
Enter amount paid:
10                          
Change back:
Total: $1.51
Ones: 1
NO QUARTERS FOR YOU!
NO DIMES FOR YOU!
Nickels: 4195472
NO PENNIES FOR YOU!
```

As you know, if your change is $1.51 (supposed to be $1.52 but thats another slightly smaller fish) then you definitely don't need 4,195,472 nickels. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance! I'm not extremely experienced in this, I'm only 3 weeks into any C programming, be gentle!

Comment: Don't include line numbers in your code.  They're not part of the actual source, and so they shouldn't be part of your post.

Comment: Oh crap I'm sorry! Thanks for the tip and edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void coinage(int change, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies)
```

Remember that in C, all arguments are passed by value, thus anything you modify in this function, aren't modified in the out world.

Change it to take pointers to simulate pass-by-reference, the signature should look like this, the body should be modified accordingly.

```
void coinage(int change, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, *int pennies)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and I have another program that does this exact same thing and uses pointers, but my teacher told me not to use them since they haven't been covered yet and they are unrelated to what he's trying to teach us with this exercise. :/

Comment: @PuppyBreath If pointers are not an option, the only way is to put this logic in `main` as well.

Comment: So it's as simple as removing the *coinage* function and sticking the variables inside the *main()* function?

Comment: If I moved the series of if-else statements in *main()* into *coinage*, and didn't mask any of the variable from *main()*, would that work as well and still remember the *main()* variable values inside the *coinage* function? Sorry if I'm bugging you about this.

Comment: +1 For answer.  @PuppyBreath You could also use a struct for all your coins(as variables pr set of coins belonging together) and return that to. Nice and clean. I would preffer a pointer here as well :)

Comment: @Stigandr I have never used a struct before, is it something I could pick up quickly or would it be easier just to move the variables like Yu Hao said? Thanks for the response, too!

Answer (score 0):

The core problem here is that the `coinage` function is designed to return multiple values but the writer has not yet learned good ways of doing so.

One alternative is to redesign the interface so that the `coinage` function only returns one value, but gets called several times. One could make it take three parameters, the amount of change, the denomination of the current coin, and the denomination of smallest coin with higher value than current. It would return a simple int representing the count for the current coin. The existing `coinage` function effectively contains this as a block of code that is repeated with only changes in the numbers, not what it is doing.

In the main function variables such as `q` would be replaced by the expression `coins(c, 25, 100)`, meaning the number of 25 unit coins for change amount `c` given existence of 100 unit coins or bills.